Google Cloud Storage Signed URL not Accessible in HTML but Works in Browser
`I'm using Python with the Google Cloud Storage library to generate signed URLs for my objects in a bucket. These URLs are meant to be embedded in HTML to display images on a webpage. However, while the signed URLs work fine when directly pasted into a browser, they do not display the images when used in the HTML code.
from google.cloud import storage
from datetime import timedelta

def list_signed_urls(bucket_name, prefix, expiration_time=3600):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blobs = bucket.list_blobs(prefix=prefix)
    
    signed_urls = []
    for blob in blobs:
  signed_url = blob.generate_signed_url(
            expiration=timedelta(seconds=expiration_time),
            method='GET'
        )
        signed_urls.append(signed_url)
    
    return signed_urls

if request.session.get('file_processed'):
    bucket_name = 'datamedical'
    positive_images = list_signed_urls(bucket_name, 'positive/')
    negative_images = list_signed_urls(bucket_name, 'negative/')
    
    context = {
        'positive_images': positive_images,
        'negative_images': negative_images,
    }
    
    return render(request, 'image/index.html', context)

    **<img src="signed_url_here" alt="Image">**

I've confirmed that the signed URLs are correct by testing them individually in a browser. However, when I use them in my HTML code like this:
`

I have solved it. Basically I just need to change my html url to this:
{% for url in positive_images %}
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="{{ url|safe }}" alt="Positive Image" />
    <p>{{ positive_file }}</p>
</div>
{% endfor %}

